# Access problem with private Git submodule using SSH

Tags: git, ssh, git-submodules

I have 2 private Git repositories on GitHub: **game-engine** and **game**.

I want to have *game-engine* as a submodule in my *game* repository. I have created both repositories, and pushed them to GitHub. My remotes are set up using *SSH* authentication and that works fine.

In both local repositories I have added my private ssh-key like so:

```bash
git config --local core.sshCommand "ssh -i <path-to-ssh-key>"
```

This has always worked for accessing my private remote repositories (e.g. now I can just use *push* and *pull*).

I then try to add *game-engine* as a submodule to *game* using the SSH url:

```bash
git submodule add git@github.com:maltebp/game-engine.git
```

But I get this error:

```bash
Cloning into 'C:/Users/malte/projects/game/game-engine'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:maltebp/game-engine.git' into submodule path 'C:/Users/malte/projects/game/game-engine' failed
```

Do I have to pass in the ssh-key manually or something?

I have found very little about this online so I don't if this is something that people rarely do?

Comment: can you try running your `git submodule ...` adding your sshCommand config: `git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -i <path-to-ssh-key>" submodule add ...` ?

Comment: Ah, brilliant - it was that simple! Thanks a lot! Will accept it as an answer if you post it as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you showed in your setup: you defined the `core.sshCommand` only locally (the `--local` in `git config --local ...`), which means that this option is written to the repository-scoped `.git/config` file.

This configuration file is not taken into account when running `git submodule add ...` so the underlying `clone` command does not use your customized `ssh -i <path-to-ssh-key>` command.

One way to circumvent that is: make that customized available during the `git submodule add ...` command

- you can override a configuration option for the duration of one single git command using `git -c ...`:
  `git -c core.sshCommand "ssh -i <path-to-ssh-key>" submodule add ...`
- or use the [`GIT_SSH` environment variable](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITSSHcode):
  `GIT_SSH="ssh -i <path-to-ssh-key>" git submodule add ...`

---

If you want to always use your dedicated ssh key for repos under `github.com/maltebp`, you can set up an alias in `.ssh/config`, then set a `url.<base>.insteadOf` to "catch" accesses to `github.com/matebp` and rewrite them using that alias.